# My Home Phone is being used to place calls to fax numbers

Tags: phone

We are using Verizon's Home Phone Connect as a replacement for our AT&T landline.  The problem is that somebody is using our phone to make dozens of calls each day to a series of toll free numbers.  When I've dialed these numbers I get a fax signal once a connection is made.  Has anyone else experienced this?

The phone is not a cell phone, but uses the Verizon network to make and receive calls.  These calls are being made, apparently from our phone, all hours of the day...whether we're home or not.  And there's no indication a call is being made while it happens.  It seems like maybe someone is trying to send information from my phone to a fax number (since my phone is not a cell, there is no vital information to get).

How can I:  a) stop this, b) figure out how this is being done to me,  c) report this to the authorities?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific phone service, not a security issue. You should contact Verizon's support and have them help you directly.